# Gesture to pop NavigationController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, core-animation

In Flurry for Twitter you can swipe to the right to pop the current ViewController. This is of course not difficult to implement, but in Flurry the two ViewControllers fade as you drag.

So my question is how I can perform the animation when a ViewController is popped as the users  swipes to the right so that the animation is not always done in like 0.3 seconds.

You can see the effect in [this video](http://youtu.be/WwouQegVDpc?hd=1&t=35s) at 0:35 - 0:38.

Comment: Thanks for correctly tagging this question with 'cocoa-touch' instead of 'Xcode'. You rock.

Answer (score 1):

Since the popping animation of UINavigationController cannot be parametrized, in my opinion the developers of Flurry did something like this:

1. Grab a reference to the current and the previous view controller in the navigation stack
2. Attach a gesture recognizer to the view of the current one - or maybe find any other way to detect finger movements
3. As the user's finger moves, animate the two views
4. When the gesture ends, *actually* pop the view controller, passing `NO` to the `animated:` parameter of the method call.